# Vencimento de datas

Tags: java, data, jdbc, javafx

Tenho esse código que valida as datas de um carnê e coloca na tabela:

```
@SuppressWarnings("nls")
public static ObservableList<String> getPagaVenci1(TableView<PersonC> jtc, String sq4, int l) throws Exception{
    Label le = new Label(sq4);
    String g = le.getText();
    ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    Date datavs = new Date();
    DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    f = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
    System.out.println(f.format(datavs));
    String datat = f.format(datavs);
    String datav = datat;
    String dataFormat = g;

    int dasf;
    int dasv;
    String dataF = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(0,10);
    int len = sq4.length();
    int lo = l;

    while(lo != 0){
        switch(len){
            case 22:
                String dataF1 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                if(len == 22){
                    System.out.println("22");
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF.replace("/", "").toString());
                    dasv = Integer.parseInt(datav.replace("/", "").toString());
                    String sd7 = "";
                    String sd8 = "";
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd7 = dataF;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");
                    }
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF1.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd8 = dataF1;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    String[] sdarr3 = {sd7,sd8};
                    System.out.println(sdarr3);
                    data.addAll(sdarr3);
                }
            case 34:
                String dataF11 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                String dataF2 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(24,34);
                if(sq4.length() == 34){
                    System.out.println("34");
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF.replace("/", "").toString());
                    dasv = Integer.parseInt(datav.replace("/", "").toString());
                    String sd4 = "";
                    String sd5 = "";
                    String sd6 = "";
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd4 = dataF; 
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");
                    }
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF11.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd5 = dataF11; 
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF2.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd6 = dataF2; 
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    String[] sdarry2 = {sd4,sd5,sd6}; 
                    System.out.println(sdarry2);
                    data.addAll(sdarry2);
                }
            case 42:
                String dataF111 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                String dataF22 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(24,34);
                if(sq4.length() == 42){
                    System.out.println("42");
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF.replace("/", "").toString());
                    dasv = Integer.parseInt(datav.replace("/", "").toString());
                    String sd = "";
                    String sd1 = "";
                    String sd2 = "";
                    String sd3 = "";
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd = dataF;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");
                    }
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF111.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd1 = dataF111;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF22.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd2 = dataF22;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    String dataF3 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(34,42);
                    dasf = Integer.parseInt(dataF3.replace("/", "").toString());
                    if(dasf <= dasv){
                        sd3 = dataF3;
                        System.out.println(sq4);
                        System.out.println("Encontrou o true.");    
                    }
                    String[] sdarry = {sd,sd1,sd2,sd3};
                    System.out.println(sdarry);
                    data.addAll(sdarry);    
                }
            lo = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(data);
    return data;
}
```

Estou tentando diminui-lo. 
E também não aparece nada na tabela.

O que faço?

---

Código das Linhas da tabela:

```
    static ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public static ObservableList<Person> SCs() {
    String sql = "SELECT NOME,DIVIDA,PAGAMENTO,DATADV FROM CLIENTES";
    String url = "Jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
    try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "AL0921069LUCASJL");
            PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()){
        int linha = 0;
        while(rs.next()){
            linha ++;
            int l = linha;
            System.out.println(l);
            String sq1 = rs.getString("NOME");
            String sq2 = rs.getString("DIVIDA");
            String sq3 = rs.getString("PAGAMENTO");
            String sq4 = rs.getString("DATADV");

            data.addAll(new Person(sq1,sq2,sq3,Person.getPagaVenci(jtc,sq4,l)));

        }
    }catch(Exception es){
        es.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("OK!");
        SI.createExceptionDialog(es, "Erro Inesperado. \n"+ "Informe ao Fornecedor. \n"+ "Erro 5.");
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Aonde e como você chama esta função? O que pode vir nos parâmetros `sq4` e `l`?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Ok, já estou tentando elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: Que strings exatamente existem dentro da coluna `DATADV`? Pergunto isso porque estou achando que tem algo errado nos tamanhos que você passa para o `subSequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu código tem muito problemas:

1. Você não forneceu a classe `PersonC` do parâmetro `jtc` (que suponho ser uma subclasse de `Person`), mas como você não parece estar usando este parâmetro para nada, podemos simplesmente eliminá-lo.
2. O `throws Exception` é desnecessário, e pode ser removido.
3. A segunda linha deste trecho é inútil:

   ```
   DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
   f = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
   ```

   Portanto ficaria apenas isso:

   ```
   DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
   ```
4. Neste trecho:

   ```
   String datat = f.format(datavs);
   String datav = datat;
   ```

   A variável `datat` não é usada nunca mais, portanto pode ser eliminada:

   ```
   String datav = f.format(datavs);
   ```
5. Nestas variáveis:

   ```
   public static ObservableList<String> getPagaVenci1(String sq4, int l) {
       Label le = new Label(sq4);
       String g = le.getText();
       // ...
       String dataFormat = g;
   ```

   Me parece que o label é inútil, e que tanto `g` quanto `dataFormat` serão sempre iguais a `sq4`.
6. As ocorrências de `subSequence` podem ser substituídas por `substring` eliminado o *cast*.
7. Nas partes `dataF.replace("/", "").toString()`, o `toString()` é totalmente desnecessário e pode ser eliminado.
8. O uso de `DateFormat.getDateInstance();` faz com que o comportamento do seu programa dependa do `Locale` padrão. Isso daí pode interferir na forma como você compara as datas.
9. O nome das variáveis poderia ser melhor!

Mas a pior parte do código é o `switch` dentro do `while`:

```
    int len = sq4.length();
    int lo = l;

    while(lo != 0){
        switch(len){
            case 22:
                String dataF1 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                if(len == 22){
                    // Bloco 1 com várias instruções.
                }
            case 34:
                String dataF11 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                String dataF2 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(24,34);
                if(sq4.length() == 34){
                    // Bloco 2 com várias instruções.
                }
            case 42:
                String dataF111 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(12,22);
                String dataF22 = (String) dataFormat.subSequence(24,34);
                if(sq4.length() == 42){
                    // Bloco 3 com várias instruções.
                }
            lo = 0;
        }
    }
```

Nesta parte:

10. O laço `while` é completamente inútil. O `lo = 0;` no final faz com que ele execute no máximo uma vez. O fato de o parâmetro `l` ser o número da linha e começar com 1, faz com que o laço sempre execute pelo menos uma vez. E se ele executa pelo menos uma vez e no máximo uma vez, então ele executa exatamente uma vez sempre, e portanto é totalmente desnecessário.
11. Ao eliminar o laço, a variável `lo` também se torna desnecessária e pode ser eliminada.
12. Ao eliminar a variável `lo`, o parâmetro `l` também se torna desnecessário.
13. As variáveis `dataF1`, `dataF11` e `dataF111` são as mesmas coisas, porém declaradas em lugares diferentes. O mesmo ocorre para `dataF2` e `dataF22`.
14. Os `if`s são desnecessários se ao invés de *fallthrough*, um `break;` fosse utilizado de forma adequada.
15. Se o tamanho da `sq4` não for nem 22, nem 34 e nem 42, o código entra em *loop* infinito!
16. Se a `String` `sq4` tiver como conteúdo coisas que não forem datas no formato correto, o resultado pode ser ou uma lista sem nenhum sentido sendo mostrada como resultado, ou um `NumberFormatException` sendo lançado.
17. O `while` e o `switch` são construções de linguagem muito inadequadas para esta circunstância e o fato de terem sido muito mal-empregadas e ainda por cima em uma circunstância aonde sequer deviam ser empregadas, demonstra que quem fez isso simplesmente não sabia o que estava fazendo, o que é reforçado pelo uso de variáveis que não deveriam ter relação com a lógica utilizada (o número da linha) e pelo uso redundante e repetitivo de múltiplas variáveis distintas com significados iguais. Aparentemente o motivo de esta gambiarra tosca ter sido feita desta forma é para tentar evitar um `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` ao executar o `subSequence` quando a `String` é pequena demais.

Com tudo isso, eu chego a conclusão que o melhor é refazer o método inteiro do zero. Então vamos analisar o código tenta fazer de fato:

1. Inicialmente ele pica a `String` `sq4` em 4 partes: De 0 a 9, de 12 a 21, de 24 a 33 e de 34 a 41. Os caracteres nas posições 10, 11, 22 e 23 são ignorados. As três primeiras `String`s resultantes têm cada uma 10 caracteres, se existirem. A última tem 8.
2. Se a `String` `sq4` for curta demais, as partes excedentes simplemente não existem.
3. Cada pedaço que existe representa uma data que é comparada com a data atual. A comparação é feita ao remover-se as barras, converter para número e verificar qual é a maior. Se a `String` representando a data estiver no passado ou presente, ela é adicionado à lista. **Caso esteja no futuro, uma `String` vazia é adicionada à lista**. Caso não exista, nada é adicionado na lista.

Para refazer o seu código vou assumir o seguinte:

1. Vou considerar que o fato de uma `String` vazia poder ser adicionada à lista é um bug e que isso nunca devia acontecer.
2. Vou considerar que as posições e tamanho dos pedaços na `String` estão corretos, mas se não estiverem, você não terá dificuldade para alterar.
3. Vou considerar que o procedimento de remover as barras e converter para números tem o propósito de saber qual data antecede ou sucede outra.
4. Vou assumir que caso a `String` não tenha um tamanho e formato válido, o melhor é lançar uma exceção.
5. Vou assumir que o formato da data sempre deveria ser `yyyy/MM/dd`. Mas se não for, você pode alterar isso facilmente. Deve ser sempre o mesmo formato que é usado no banco de dados.
6. **Acho que o fato de a última parte da `String` ter tamanho 8 é um grave bug no seu código**, pois ele não vai dar certo com este tamanho a menos que por alguma razão, esta parte da `String` não tenha as barras ou o ano tenha só dois dígitos. Mas vou manter deste jeito porque isso é algo que até o momento só você pode arrumar porque só você sabe, até o momento, como as informações são guardadas no seu banco de dados. Se o tamanho dela fosse 10, a `String` teria que ter tamanho 44. Pode ser também que as posições escolhidas - 0, 12, 24 e 34 - estejam erradas, e talvez o correto seria 0, 11, 22 e 33, que faria mais sentido, mas a `String` teria que ter tamanho 43 neste caso. De qualquer forma, isso é fácil de ser alterado no código a seguir.

Eis então o código resultante:

```
    private static void adicionarData(SimpleDateFormat f, String dataDvStr, int comeco, int tamanho, Date agora, List<String> destino) {
        if (dataDvStr.length() < comeco + tamanho) return;
        String data = dataDvStr.substring(comeco, comeco + tamanho);
        try {
            if (!f.parse(data).after(agora)) destino.add(data);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data inválida.", ex);
        }
    }

    public static ObservableList<String> getPagaVenci1(String dataDvStr) {
        ObservableList<String> resultado = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Date agora = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

        int len = dataDvStr.length();
        if (len != 22 && len != 34 && len != 42) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tamanho inválido.");

        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr,  0, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr, 12, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr, 24, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr, 34,  8, agora, resultado); // 8!? WTF? Isso daqui só pode estar errado!
        return resultado;
    }
```

Se a última `String` de fato tiver o tamanho 8, diferentemente das outras três, mas use um formato de data diferente, então você deverá instanciar mais um `SimpleDateFormat` com o formato adequado e passá-lo para esta última chamada. Supondo que o formato da última data seja `yyyyMMdd`, ficaria assim:

```
    public static ObservableList<String> getPagaVenci1(String dataDvStr) {
        ObservableList<String> resultado = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        Date agora = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        int len = dataDvStr.length();
        if (len != 22 && len != 34 && len != 42) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tamanho inválido.");

        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr,  0, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr, 12, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f, dataDvStr, 24, 10, agora, resultado);
        adicionarData(f2, dataDvStr, 34,  8, agora, resultado); // Usa um SimpleDateFormat especial aqui!
        return resultado;
    }
```

Novamente, se as datas tiverem formatos diferentes, você deverá usar um `SimpleDateFormat` para cada formato distinto.

---

Por fim, ainda temos o seu método `SCs`. Nele eu tenho poucas alterações a fazer:

1. O método `getPagaVenci` (ou `getPagaVenci1`) teve os parâmetros alterados.
2. Não é boa prática manter uma lista mutável em uma variável global. Vamos fazer o método retornara uma nova lista ao invés de retornar a variável global.
3. Não tem sentido ter duas variáveis `l` e `linha` que representam exatamente a mesma coisa.
4. O nome de algumas variáveis poderia ser melhor.

Assim o seu método `SCs` fica assim:

```
    public static ObservableList<Person> SCs() {
        ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        String sql = "SELECT NOME,DIVIDA,PAGAMENTO,DATADV FROM CLIENTES";
        String url = "Jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "AL0921069LUCASJL");
                PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
            int linha = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                linha++;
                System.out.println(linha);
                String nome = rs.getString("NOME");
                String divida = rs.getString("DIVIDA");
                String pagamento = rs.getString("PAGAMENTO");
                String dataDv = rs.getString("DATADV");

                data.addAll(new Person(nome, divida, pagamento, Person.getPagaVenci(dataDv)));
            }
        } catch (Exception es) {
            es.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("OK!");
            SI.createExceptionDialog(es, "Erro Inesperado. \nInforme ao Fornecedor. \nErro 5.");
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Ou talvez o propósito deste método `SCs` seja o de atualizar a lista `data`? Se for este o caso, ficaria melhor assim:

```
    private ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public void SCs() {
        data.clear();
        String sql = "SELECT NOME,DIVIDA,PAGAMENTO,DATADV FROM CLIENTES";
        String url = "Jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "system", "AL0921069LUCASJL");
                PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
            int linha = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                linha++;
                System.out.println(linha);
                String nome = rs.getString("NOME");
                String divida = rs.getString("DIVIDA");
                String pagamento = rs.getString("PAGAMENTO");
                String dataDv = rs.getString("DATADV");

                data.addAll(new Person(nome, divida, pagamento, Person.getPagaVenci(dataDv)));
            }
        } catch (Exception es) {
            es.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("OK!");
            SI.createExceptionDialog(es, "Erro Inesperado. \nInforme ao Fornecedor. \nErro 5.");
        }
    }
```

Observe também o seguinte:

- Neste último trecho de código, eu tirei o `static`. Isso elimina o uso de variáveis globais e de muitos problemas associados a elas. Você então passará a trabalhar com instâncias da sua classe DAO.
- Você pode mover coisas como a URL do banco de dados, o nome de usuário e a senha para campos do seu DAO, evitando-o ter que repeti-los em cada método que for acessar o banco de dados. Isso também te dá a possibilidade de mudá-los facilmente se for necessário.
- Não é boa prática de programação misturar lógica de visualização (JavaFX) com lógica de acesso ao banco de dados, e é exatamente isso que você está fazendo no seu método `SCs`. O ideal seria você usar `ArrayList` ao invés de `ObservableList` na sua lógica de banco de dados e nas suas classe de modelo (`Person`). E adicionar os elementos a uma `ObservableList` fora do seu DAO.
- Para evitar de misturar lógica de visualização com lógica de acesso à dados no tratamento de exceções, as exceções ocorridas no DAO deveriam ser lançadas para fora do método (usando `throw`) e capturadas na camada acima para então serem exibidas ao usuário ou tratadas.
- O fato de você estar colocando quatro datas em um mesmo campo no banco de dados, é uma violação da [primeira forma normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). Como resultado, pesquisar ou alterar valores dentro deste campo se torna muito difícil e trabalhoso. O ideal é normalizar isso daí com um relacionamento *1-para-N*.
- Convenhamos que `SCs` e `getPagaVenci1` não são bom nomes para métodos!

Comment: Obrigado por ter todo esse trabalho de corrigir esse código, Desculpe por não explicar e também por você ter feito o tudo do zero.

Comment: @lucasdaniel Tudo bem. Fico grato por ter ajudado.